# Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'System.Windows.Forms.Label'

Tags: c#

The code that is causing the problem is

```
txtResult.Text = Convert.ToString(step3);
```

and it produces the error

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to
>   'System.Windows.Forms.Label'

See this image:

[image]

Comment: Instead of an image, you should copy your code directly. <strike>But are you absolutely sure you have `txtResult.Text =` and not simply `txtResult =`?</strike> Never mind that, I looked at your image.

Comment: Can you post the code where `txtResult` is defined? If it is indeed a Label, that error is probably leftover from a previous build where you did indeed forget the `.Text`. (In fact the location of the squiggly indicates just that.) Try rebuilding your project.

Comment: Have you tried running it actually? It could be an intellisense artifact

Comment: In fact, ignore my first comment entirely - this is one example where an image-of-my-code is indeed valuable. And you have copied the relevant code into the question. Let me inline that image for you.

Comment: The error was caused by the *previous* txtResult = Convert.ToString(), before you put .Text, I think

Answer (score 1):

Going by the image, it would appear you are not actually having this issue. Intellisense will often leave previous compilation errors hanging around until you attempt another compilation - this is most notable in your image because the blue line indicating en error is off and does not cover the entire line. Always build or rebuild your code before assuming an error is still occurring.